# gitlab-ci docker executor | how to setup mysql service?

Tags: mysql, spring, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to get a gitlab-ci build going, but I'm having trouble with the mysql setup portion. When I commit, the mysql script seems to run OK, but then the application build fails on connecting to the db. What am I missing here?

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
stages:
  - prepare
  - test

services:
  - mariadb

variables:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"

connect:
  stage: prepare
  image: mysql
  script:
  - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb < "data/db/scripts/create-db.sql"
  - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb < "data/db/scripts/init-db-tables.sql"

dev:
  stage: test
  image: java:opendjdk-8
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
    - ./gradlew check
```

**data source config**

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://mariadb:3306/rvep");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    return dataSource;
}
```

**build errors**
result of hibernate config not hitting db

```java
io.abnd.rvep.RVEPTests > contextLoads FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException

io.abnd.rvep.security.rest.TestControllerTest > findAllRoleCategories FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException

io.abnd.rvep.security.rest.TestControllerTest > findAllRoles FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems installing mysql-client through apt-get, and combining scripts helps. Here is my **.gitlab-ci.yml** *for now*. build passing.

```yaml
variables:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"

dev:
  image: java:openjdk-8
  services:
    - mariadb
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install mysql-client
    - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb < "data/db/scripts/create-db.sql"
    - mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb < "data/db/scripts/init-db-tables.sql"
    - ./gradlew assemble check --info
```

Answer (score 5):

First make sure to read carefully the "What is service" and "How is service linked to the build" sections in documentation: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-service

In your configuration, you are starting the **mysql** service in these two lines:

```
services:
  - mysql
```

Thanks to this in your build containers you can use a **mysql** service which is available on standard port by the hostame *mysql*.

Here:

```
connect:
  image: mysql
  script:
  - service mysql start
  - echo "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');" | mysql -u root
  - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h mysql "$MYSQL_DATABASE"
  - mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h localhost < "data/db/scripts/create-db.sql"
  - mysql -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h localhost < "data/db/scripts/init-db-tables.sql"
```

You are starting a new build **inside of a container started from mysql image** and prepare a database state **locally**! None of those commands even touch your *mysql* service.

Instead of this you should run the *connect* job inside of a container that will have a mysql client on board (it can be also this *mysql* one), but run all commands on a host **mysql** and not on a host **localhost**.

Second thing is that you are running those two jobs - *connect* and *dev* in one stage, so they will be executed in parallel (but with a limitation set in the runner's configuration).

You should add first - as a top-level entry:

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - test
```

and then modify those two jobs to:

```
connect:
  stage: prepare
  (...)

dev:
  stage: test
  (...)
```

After this jobs from the first stage (*prepare*) will be executed in parallel, then jobs from the second stage (*test*) will be executed in parallel etc.

Comment: even with some changes, I seem to be in the same spot.

Comment: Yes, in java config you should also change the db hostname from localhost to mysql